# Remove View Controller from memory?

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, uiviewcontroller, subview

I seem to be having some trouble finding the answer to this one.

My Application loads view controllers using this code:

```
World_Pick *world_pick = [[World_Pick alloc] initWithNibName:@"World Pick" 
bundle:nil];

world_pick.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:world_pick animated:YES];

[world_pick release];
```

The problem is the previous view isnt being released from memory, and just adding on to it. I have tried stuff like

```
[self.view removeFromSubview];
[viewController release];
ViewController = nil;
```

None of which seem to work. Could someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the view that is now underneath the new modal view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you mean, I would say that it is normal, when you present a view controller modally that the underlying view controller is not removed and the view remains there. This is how modal view controllers are presented asa far as I know.

I don´t know what UI you are trying to build into your app, but maybe you should look into using a [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or, possibly, just adding/removing your views to a base view as need arise. This is of course just a guess, I don´t know what you are trying to do but if you provide more detail, I can help further.

Comment: Well the thing is my app loads so many Nib files, and each one is stored in memory, and it keeps building in the memory. what i want is to be able to load a new view and then dismiss the old one.

Comment: I have not perfectly clear what you are doing; if you want a modal view to be removed from memory, you can call `–dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` on its controller; if you do not do that and keep presenting controllers, there is no way out of filling up memory. In fact, if it is the case you should not use modal views, but UINavigationController; you can obtain any animation effect you want with it,if that is your concern...

Answer (score 1):

The view controller that's presenting world_pick, the one that's `self` in the code above, should probably be left alone -- it's presenting a modal view controller, after all, and you'll go back to that view controller when the modal controller is dismissed. The view that it manages should also be left alone. It may be unloaded if there's a memory warning, but if there's memory available it should remain so that it's in place when the modal view controller is dismissed.

Is there some reason you're concerned about this?

Comment: Because im not dismissing any view controllers, they all lead to other ones.

Comment: `-presentModalViewController:animated:` is probably not the best way to display your view controllers, then. Presenting modally implies that the view controller is part of a "mode" that will end at some point and return back to the previous controller. For pointers on how to install your own view controller as the only, top-level controller (as opposed to using a nav controller, for example) look at an empty view-based project's app delegate. However, that's not not not good UI -- the user should normally be able to go back if he/she wants to.

Comment: Ahh I see, Is there any way to still do the same type of animation by doing basically what the delegate does? Thanks for the response also